Reading Access DB File From NAS in VBA
After lots of Google searching (and to my surprise) I failed to obtain an answer to what I consider to be a simple question. I just purchased a Synology NAS and saved some MS Access files on it. I have two computers, a desktop (Windows 10) and a laptop (Windows 11) and the first one is connected to the local network (also used by the NAS) while the laptop is not. On the desktop I could easily see the NAS device (under This PC--->Network) and I could read data from one of the Access files from VBA, with the standard code below:
 Dim connObj as Object: Set connObj = CreateObject("ADODB Connection")

 Dim dataSet as Object: Set dataSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

 Dim szConn as string, sqlString as string

 szConn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & \_ 

 "DataSource=\\\\MyNAS\\home\\Main Folder\\WindVelocityData.accdb"

  connObj.Open szConn

  sqlString="SELECT \* FROM \[Oslo Wind\];"

Etc. Etc.
This works just fine, but when I try doing the same thing via the laptop (it not being connected to LAN splitter) of course it does not work. The problem must be the DataSource (the file path). The laptop is technically not in the local network, just having internet access via the router Wi-Fi. Now, upon setting up the NAS, Synology gives you a dedicated URL link for quick connection to your NAS. Should I use that? If so how? Not to mention that the NAS is obviously password protected (it asks for username and password) Any ideas how to solve this? I might as well use MS C# to do the same task, but I imagine the problem will be the same regardless the language use, i.e. trying to read a file from outside the local network. Thanks!
I checked many posts on this issue, but none was this specific. Some were saying I need to create a VPN with the NAS and connect the laptop via this VPN. Even if I get to do this (I am clueless about VPNs), I imagine the path file with user name and password must still be provided by the code somehow to gain access to the file.

The laptop is technically not in the local network ... but that is exactly what is needed for you to access its file share with the folder holding the accdb file.

Hello Gustav, I knew you might say something like this as this comment was often made on the posts I read. So yes, it makes sense, the laptop is not connected to the network via an ethernet cable and it is outside. But then, Synology gives you a URL which looks like this: https://quickconnect.to/XXXX, where XXXX is provided by the user upon set up. And then, you can access the NAS from anywhere as long as you have internet connection. So, if you can connect to the NAS and see the files in this way, why couldn't you read a data file from it using code?

If you want to do this, then you must use an address like quickconnect.to/XXXX and the one you show in your code (\\\\MyNAS\\home\\...).

Why \ characters in SQL statement?

Also, be aware of this

Is quickconnect web based? Word, Excel is WHOLE FILE based, and can be used on skydrive, onedrive etc.? Access databases don't work that way, and they don't load the whole file, and when you exit Access there is no file save command. Hence, Access does not work on OneDrive or any kind of cloud based system that uses a web browser to supply the files. Only a VALID windows file path and VALID windows networking path name is permitted. This is due to that unlike the rest of office, Access is a database system, and does NOT work on the whole file, but is able to modify bits and parts of that file
